# Reading long binary numbers in java

Tags: java, binary, number-formatting

I am trying to write a program which converts binary numbers into decimal, however as soon as I have a binary number which is bigger than 10 digits I get a java.lang.numberformatexception error. I was wondering how I should rewrite my code in order to handle binary numbers:

```
try{
                //will throw an exception if the user's input contains a non-Integer
                int inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(returnEnterNumber());
                //when our user wants to convert from binary to decimal
                if(binaryToDecimal.isSelected()){
                    //checks if number is binary
                    int checkNumber = inputNumber;
                    while (checkNumber != 0) {
                        if (checkNumber % 10 > 1) {
                            throw new InvalidBinaryException();
                        }
                        checkNumber = checkNumber / 10;
                    }
                    //converts from binary and outputs result
                    int n = Integer.parseInt(returnEnterNumber(), 2);
                    displayConvertedNumber(Integer.toString(n));
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)  {
                displayConvertedNumber("WRONG INPUT! - TRY again");
            }
```

Edit: I understand why the code fails, seeing as how it takes the number as a decimal and overflows. I am not sure how to rewrite the code to take the input as a binary straight away.

Comment: It's because an `Integer` will have a max value of 2147483647. Consider `BigInteger` if you will have a length of more than 10 digits

Comment: You can use a `long` for up to 18 digits. For larger than this, Use BigInteger.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a valid way to check a binary number. You're converting to an `int` in base 10, then checking that each of the digits in base 10 is zero or one. The conversion itself will fail on long enough input strings, and if it doesn't the checking will fail as well.

You shouldn't be converting it all all, you should be checking the input string itself.

**EDIT** Actually you don't have to do anything. `Integer.parseInt()` will check it for you and throw `NumberFormatException` if the string isn't a number in the specified radix.

Comment: What is an efficient way to check the input string to avoid reading the number in base 10?

Comment: I have this:

public static String returnDecimal(String s){

    
  int n = Integer.parseInt(s, 2);  
  return String.valueOf(n);  
 }  
  
I still overflow with a big enough input though

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing your binary digit string as a decimal integer first.  If it has more than 10 significant digits then its *decimal* interpretation is too big to fit in an `int`, so the decimal conversion fails.

When you are going to parse the digit string as a binary number, simply avoid first parsing it as a decimal one.  For instance, most of what you posted could be reduced to this:

```
int inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(returnEnterNumber(), 
        binaryToDecimal.isSelected() ? 2 : 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Integers MAX values:

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] arg) {
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);   

System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE);   

 }
}
```

the output will be:

```
2147483647
-2147483648
```

This means that if you have more than 10 digits, you have exceeded the max number for the `Integer` data type.
Try Using `BigInteger` on your binary value or consider returning it as `String`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one line of code that will accomplish what you are looking for

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger("10101010101010111101010101001101010101010101001010101010101001011101010101010101",2).toString());
```